# Button Images Don't Show When Using Xcode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uibutton

I have several buttons with images assigned to each.  In Xcode 4.6 using the iOS 6 SDK, they show like they should.  When using Xcode 5 with the iOS 7 SDK, the images are not there.  In the xib it says an image is on the button but it doesn't appear.  Any ideas why?

iOS 6:
[image]

iOS 7:
[image]

Comment: Did you set tint color of your buttons?

Comment: The images you have attached are they screen dumps of the XIB or the running app ? Is it showing question marks on the xib ? Are you changing or setting the images programatically ?

Comment: @johnMa, the color showing in Xcode 5 is the default tint color.

Comment: @RyanHeitner, Those are screenshots from the app running in the simulator.  There are no question marks in the xib and the images are set in the xib.

Comment: Try set tint color clear color.

Comment: Use this code for set image UIImage *firstimage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"notificationselected.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

Comment: This comment above worked great for me!

Answer (score 3):

For me, my problem was that the button type was set to System instead of Custom. They displayed fine in iOS 6.0 and iOS 6.1 Simulators, just not iOS 7.0 simulator. I'm not sure how this happened as I'm pretty sure it's the first time the project had been opened in Xcode 5 with iOS 7.0 sdk. I had three buttons, 1 showed fine because it was a Custom button, and the other two did not show their images, but could be pressed. Once set to Custom button types, all worked great, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the images to appear after setting the tint color to clear and setting the image and background image to what I wanted.  In Xcode 4 I didn't have to change any of that and I didn't have to set the background image, just the image.

Comment: If you don't set your images to UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal, then they appear as template images (tint color where opaque, no color where transparent) -- this is the standard behavior for buttons in iOS 7. You should look at the document, "Buttons", that's linked to at the top of the UIButton class reference.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is `iOS7` issue.

Set bottom margin of the image/label through autolayout then try this code in your `viewDidLoad` and this should work.

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)])
{
    [self prefersStatusBarHidden];
    [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
}
else
{
    // iOS 6
}
```